# Problem in writing special characters to a properties file in Java

Tags: java, properties-file

I need to add key value pairs to a properties file. 
All are working fine except # and = everytine a \ is appended before the characters.

Please share me any suggestion.

current properties file data

paper = Normalised

I want to comment this key

#paper = Normalised

but what is happening is \ is getting added

\#paper = Normalised

'''

```
      String valueOfKey = updatedMap.get(key);

      updatedMap.remove(key);

      updatedMap.put("#" + key, valueOfKey);

   String totalPath = propertiesService.getFilePath(request) + "\\" + propertiesModel.getSelectedFile();

      propertiesService.updatePropertyfile(updatedMap, request, totalPath);
```

'''

'''

```
public boolean updatePropertyfile(Map<String, String> map, HttpServletRequest request, String fileName) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
Writer Out = null;
      File file = new File(fileName);
try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
        Set<String> keyset = map.keySet();
        Iterator iter = keyset.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          String key = (String) iter.next();
          props.setProperty(key, (String) map.get(key));
   }
        props.store(Out, "update");
        Out.flush();
        Out.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
      }
 return true;
    }
```

'''

Value in property file getting written

- \#paper = Normalised

Comment: That might be by design because `#` and `=` are special characters in `.properties` files. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve] and descript the problem you have.

Comment: The key for that entry is `#paper` and the value is `Normalised`, just as you wrote it with `updatedMap.put("#" + key, valueOfKey);`. Again, what is the problem you have the way it is saved in the `.properties` file?

Comment: Note: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase. So `Out` should be `out`.

Comment: Also note that you are using thr raw type `Iterator`. **Never use raw types**; always provide the necessary type arguments. So `Iterator` should be `Iterator<String>`. That'll also make the cast to `String` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The hash tag is the lead-in for a comment in Java Properties files:

```
# Created by generator on 2020-05-01
#current properties file data
paper = Normalised

#want to update like
#paper = Normalised – but this is a comment …

#but what is happening is \# is getting added
\#paper = Normalised # Backslash required …
```

So the escape with the backslash is the only way to get it working.

Unfortunately, when you need to read the Properties file with another API than `java.util.Properties`, you have to add this capability to your parser.

Comment: Acutally i want to comment it.

Comment: You want to "deactivate" the entry `paper = normalised`, by prepending the line with a hashtag? That does not work that way, not when using the `java.util.Properties` API: it allows to write only a file comment on saving/storing the file, but not when adding a property value.

Comment: Yes, i guess you are right.   Store method in property class doesn't allow escape char. 
   'public void store(OutputStream out, String comments)
        throws IOException
    {
        store0(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "8859_1")),
               comments,
               true);
    }'